# Redirected URL picking up the Auth token from the Angular application

Tags: angular, http, amazon-s3, redirect, http-status-code-302

I am creating an Angular app, where I need to download a huge file from S3. Since AWS doesn't allow more than 10MB downloads via APIG, I am using a pre-signed URL for download.

We need to protect this URL for which I have created a regular APIG resource that redirects to the pre-signed S3 link with a 302 status code from a Spring boot App.

The issue however is that when the redirected link gets triggered in the browser, it automatically passes along the Authorization token with the request. The pre-signed link already has a token attached to it and thus the request fails with a 400 Bad Request. It errors out saying: Only a single auth mechanism is supported.

I have tried capturing the redirect link in my HTTP interceptor but that request doesn't come to my interceptor either. If it is not coming to the interceptor, I am not sure where is it picking the auth token from, because I append the Authorization header in the interceptor only.

Is this a default browser mechanism to append the Auth from the original request to the redirected link ? Has anyone faced this before ? Any links or suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Please provide the interceptor code and how you injected that in the angular module code

Comment: I am using the Angular http interceptor to add Authorization to all outgoing requests that are originating from my app.